# Is Oracle MySQL the same as MySQL?

Tags: mysql, oracle

I have MySQL on a system, and I am trying to determine if it is Oracle MySQL, or MySQL.  Is there a difference between Oracle MySQL:

http://www.oracle.com/us/products/mysql/index.html

and "regular" MySQL:

http://www.mysql.com/

or are they the same thing?

Comment: Scroll to the very bottom of the mysql page, look at the logo on the right...

Comment: It's the same thing. MySQL was being developed under the auspices of Sun Microsystems, and Oracle bought Sun. The code isn't "owned" by Oracle (or Sun previously) as it is open source, but the branding and name is probably copyrighted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is the same product, Oracle only rebranded the product when acquired Sun ...

Answer (score 3):

Oracle bought SUN and got MySQL, [Source1](http://www.linux-mag.com/id/7309/), [Source2](http://blogs.gnome.org/bolsh/2009/04/20/oracle-buys-mysql-shocker-and-they-get-the-rest-of-sun-too/)

Answer (score 3):

As far as the database, yes.   when they bought sun who had previously acquired mysql